# Why does this pattern not match after the “-”?

Tags: regex, perl, grep

I have the following pattern which should work in C++ regex, perl and grep.  Does anyone know why the string of 0000 is not matching after the minus sign -?

```
$ echo AB 00000-0000 | grep -Po "(\w{2}\s*\d{5}(−\d{4})?)"
AB 00000
$ echo AB00000-0000 | grep -Po "(\w{2}\s*\d{5}(−\d{4})?)"
AB00000
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your minus sign isn't what you think it is.  When I copy and paste your code into my shell, I see:

```
echo AB00000-0000 | grep -Po "(\w{2}\s*\d{5}(\342\210\222\d{4})?)"
```

When I use a plain old minus sign (instead of `\342\210\222`, this is what I get:

```
$ echo AB00000-0000 | grep -Po "(\w{2}\s*\d{5}-\d{4}?)"
AB00000-0000
```

Comment: @notaorb - As you learned (and perhaps knew already), there are several dash characters. If your input really has an n-dash in it (medium width), then the solution is not to replace it with a hyphen in the original string, but instead it is to use an n-dash in the regular expression as well, so it will match the input string as is. https://www.chicagomanualofstyle.org/qanda/data/faq/topics/HyphensEnDashesEmDashes/faq0002.html

Answer (score 2):

It looks like the dash literal you used in your regular expression is not the same dash as is in the input.  The input dash is a small -, while the dash in your regexp is slightly longer.  Not sure how your input device is different, but when I swapped your dash for a short dash: - your expression worked fine.

(\w{2}\s*\d{5}(-\d{4})?)

Here's a great tool that might help you, I use it a lot: 
https://regex101.com/